# My sqllite database gets reset every time I push changes, hosted on Openshift

Tags: python, flask, openshift

I have a basic webapp that is hosted at Openshift and is written in Python/Flask. Recently I added a registration feature that stores user data to a SQLite database. The database is located in the main app folder.

When I test the page out it appears to be functioning correctly; users info flows into the database when data is entered on the registration page. The problem is that every time I push changes to the app the database file is reset. Changes in the database aren't reflected in the files if I try to pull the with a git pull or git fetch origin.

Is there a way for database changes to be committed remotely so I can pull them, make any needed changes and push to the origin without losing data?

Alternatively I've read that Openshift has an environment variable OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR that doesn't get rewritten when new changes are deployed. It would be great to just save the database here. Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out how properly to do this using the reference materials I've read up to this point. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct, you should save any file you want to persist in `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` that it's a environment variable defined when your program run on openshift. You should use it as base dir for your sqllite db.

```
import os
basedir = os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR')

import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(basedir,'example.db'))
```

Alternatively on openshift you could add to your gear a mysql database.